# Top bar in gnome 42 in my ubuntu 22.04.1 blinking

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension

Hi its hard to explain but i show a video:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RLRNbuIlznPPdu0Z8IkhIWWYUeMWr13M/view?usp=sharing

It seems that There are some kind of second top bar behind my official top bar...

Edit 1:
Sorry but the video seems it has no enough fps recording you cant appreciate the blink. Id try to search a vokoscreen or whatever to try to capture desktop with video with higher fps or resolution. It blinks very quickly and appear a temperature at the left of the temperature of openweather extension, also appears something behind livepatch icon. I tried to reboot and began with zero extensions.

Some info:

```
eduardo@MiPcLinux:~$ dpkg -l | grep gnome-shell > packages.txt
eduardo@MiPcLinux:~$ cat packages.txt
ii  chrome-gnome-shell                                          10.1-5                                                         all          GNOME Shell extensions integration for web browsers
ii  gnome-shell                                                 42.4-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                                          amd64        graphical shell for the GNOME desktop
ii  gnome-shell-common                                          42.4-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                                          all          common files for the GNOME graphical shell
ii  gnome-shell-extension-appindicator                          42-2~fakesync1                                                 all          AppIndicator, KStatusNotifierItem and tray support for GNOME Shell
ii  gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons-ng                      43-2ubuntu1                                                    all          desktop icon support for GNOME Shell
ii  gnome-shell-extension-manager                               0.3.0-0ubuntu2.1                                               amd64        Utility for managing GNOME Shell Extensions
ii  gnome-shell-extension-prefs                                 42.4-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                                          amd64        tool to enable / disable GNOME Shell extensions
ii  gnome-shell-extension-system-monitor                        38+git20200414-32cc79e-1                                       all          Display system information in GNOME Shell status bar
ii  gnome-shell-extension-trash                                 0.2.0-git20161122.ad29112-2                                    all          trash applet for GNOME shell
ii  gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock                           72~ubuntu5.22.04.1                                             all          Ubuntu Dock for GNOME Shell
ii  gnome-shell-extension-weather                               0~20170402.git34506a6-2                                        all          weather extension for GNOME Shell
ii  gnome-shell-extensions                                      42.1-0ubuntu1                                                  all          Extensions to extend functionality of GNOME Shell
ii  yaru-theme-gnome-shell                                      22.04.4                                                        all          Yaru GNOME Shell desktop theme from the Ubuntu Community
```

More info:

```
eduardo@MiPcLinux:~$ gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.shell > shellsettings.txt
eduardo@MiPcLinux:~$ cat shellsettings.txt 
org.gnome.shell always-show-log-out true
org.gnome.shell app-picker-layout [{'org.gnome.Geary.desktop': <{'position': <0>}>, 'org.gnome.Contacts.desktop': <{'position': <1>}>, 'org.gnome.Weather.desktop': <{'position': <2>}>, 'org.gnome.clocks.desktop': <{'position': <3>}>, 'org.gnome.Maps.desktop': <{'position': <4>}>, 'org.gnome.Books.desktop': <{'position': <5>}>, 'org.gnome.Photos.desktop': <{'position': <6>}>, 'org.gnome.Totem.desktop': <{'position': <7>}>, 'org.gnome.Calculator.desktop': <{'position': <8>}>, 'org.gnome.gedit.desktop': <{'position': <9>}>, 'simple-scan.desktop': <{'position': <10>}>, 'org.gnome.Settings.desktop': <{'position': <11>}>, 'gnome-system-monitor.desktop': <{'position': <12>}>, 'org.gnome.Boxes.desktop': <{'position': <13>}>, 'org.gnome.Terminal.desktop': <{'position': <14>}>, 'Utilities': <{'position': <15>}>, 'org.gnome.Characters.desktop': <{'position': <16>}>, 'yelp.desktop': <{'position': <17>}>, 'org.gnome.Screenshot.desktop': <{'position': <18>}>, 'org.gnome.Cheese.desktop': <{'position': <19>}>, 'org.gnome.font-viewer.desktop': <{'position': <20>}>}]
org.gnome.shell command-history ['', 'reboot', 'r']
org.gnome.shell development-tools true
org.gnome.shell disable-extension-version-validation false
org.gnome.shell disable-user-extensions false
org.gnome.shell disabled-extensions @as []
org.gnome.shell enabled-extensions ['weather-extension@xeked.com', 'LogOutButton@kyle.aims.ac.za', 'weatherintheclock@JasonLG1979.github.io', 'hibernate-status@dromi', 'RemoveAppMenu@pemmoura.com', 'user-theme@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com', 'system-monitor-next@paradoxxx.zero.gmail.com', 'openweather-extension@jenslody.de', 'native-window-placement@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com', 'screenshot-window-sizer@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com', 'window-list@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com', 'hplip-menu2@grizzlysmit.smit.id.au']
org.gnome.shell favorite-apps ['org.gnome.Calculator.desktop', 'org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop', 'update-manager.desktop', 'org.gnome.Terminal.desktop', 'firefox.desktop', 'virtualbox.desktop', 'synaptic.desktop', 'geany.desktop', 'atom_atom.desktop', 'simple-scan.desktop', 'libreoffice-writer.desktop', 'org.gnome.Software.desktop', 'chromium_chromium.desktop']
org.gnome.shell had-bluetooth-devices-setup false
org.gnome.shell looking-glass-history @as []
org.gnome.shell remember-mount-password false
org.gnome.shell welcome-dialog-last-shown-version '42.4'
org.gnome.shell.keybindings focus-active-notification ['<Super>n']
org.gnome.shell.keybindings open-application-menu ['<Super>F10']
org.gnome.shell.keybindings screenshot ['<Shift>Print']
org.gnome.shell.keybindings screenshot-window ['<Alt>Print']
org.gnome.shell.keybindings shift-overview-down ['<Super><Alt>Down']
org.gnome.shell.keybindings shift-overview-up ['<Super><Alt>Up']
org.gnome.shell.keybindings show-screen-recording-ui ['<Ctrl><Shift><Alt>R']
org.gnome.shell.keybindings show-screenshot-ui ['Print']
org.gnome.shell.keybindings switch-to-application-1 ['<Super>1']
org.gnome.shell.keybindings switch-to-application-2 ['<Super>2']
org.gnome.shell.keybindings switch-to-application-3 ['<Super>3']
org.gnome.shell.keybindings switch-to-application-4 ['<Super>4']
org.gnome.shell.keybindings switch-to-application-5 ['<Super>5']
org.gnome.shell.keybindings switch-to-application-6 ['<Super>6']
org.gnome.shell.keybindings switch-to-application-7 ['<Super>7']
org.gnome.shell.keybindings switch-to-application-8 ['<Super>8']
org.gnome.shell.keybindings switch-to-application-9 ['<Super>9']
org.gnome.shell.keybindings toggle-application-view ['<Super>a']
org.gnome.shell.keybindings toggle-message-tray ['<Super>v', '<Super>m']
org.gnome.shell.keybindings toggle-overview ['<Super>s']
```

More:

```
eduardo@MiPcLinux:~$ lspci -kv > lspci.txt
eduardo@MiPcLinux:~$ cat lspci.txt 
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 8th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] 8th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: skl_uncore
    Kernel modules: ie31200_edac

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation CoffeeLake-S GT2 [UHD Graphics 630] (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    DeviceName:  Onboard IGD
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] CometLake-S GT2 [UHD Graphics 630]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 133
    Memory at de000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at c0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at f000 [size=64]
    Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [virtual] [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915

00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th/8th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th/8th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 11
    Memory at df22f000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>

00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 200 Series/Z370 Chipset Family USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] 200 Series/Z370 Chipset Family USB 3.0 xHCI Controller
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 124
    Memory at df210000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
    Kernel modules: xhci_pci

00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH Thermal Subsystem
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] 200 Series PCH Thermal Subsystem
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 11
    Memory at df22e000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>

00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH CSME HECI #1
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] 200 Series PCH CSME HECI
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 134
    Memory at df22d000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me
    Kernel modules: mei_me

00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH SATA controller [AHCI mode] (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] 200 Series PCH SATA controller [AHCI mode]
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 123
    Memory at df228000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Memory at df22c000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    I/O ports at f090 [size=8]
    I/O ports at f080 [size=4]
    I/O ports at f060 [size=32]
    Memory at df22b000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f0) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 120
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: [disabled]
    Memory behind bridge: [disabled]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: [disabled]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev f0) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 121
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=02, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 0000e000-0000efff [size=4K]
    Memory behind bridge: df100000-df1fffff [size=1M]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: [disabled]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f0) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 122
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=03, subordinate=03, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: [disabled]
    Memory behind bridge: df000000-df0fffff [size=1M]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: [disabled]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Z370 Chipset LPC/eSPI Controller
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Z370 Chipset LPC/eSPI Controller
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0

00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation 200 Series/Z370 Chipset Family Power Management Controller
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] 200 Series/Z370 Chipset Family Power Management Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Memory at df224000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]

00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH HD Audio
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] 200 Series PCH HD Audio
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 135
    Memory at df220000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at df200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation 200 Series/Z370 Chipset Family SMBus Controller
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] 200 Series/Z370 Chipset Family SMBus Controller
    Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 16
    Memory at df22a000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    I/O ports at f040 [size=32]
    Kernel driver in use: i801_smbus
    Kernel modules: i2c_i801

02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 19
    I/O ports at e000 [size=256]
    Memory at df104000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Memory at df100000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169

03:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM981/PM981/PM983 (prog-if 02 [NVM Express])
    Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd SSD 970 EVO Plus 1TB
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16, NUMA node 0
    Memory at df000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: nvme
    Kernel modules: nvme


eduardo@MiPcLinux:~$ cd ~/.local/share/gnome-shell
eduardo@MiPcLinux:~/.local/share/gnome-shell$ ls -l
total 12
-rw-rw-r--  1 eduardo eduardo 3947 sep  6 14:04 application_state
drwxrwxr-x 18 eduardo eduardo 4096 sep  5 20:21 extensions
drwxr-xr-x  2 eduardo eduardo 4096 sep  2 20:05 extension-updates
-rw-r--r--  1 eduardo eduardo    0 sep 27  2020 gnome-overrides-migrated
eduardo@MiPcLinux:~/.local/share/gnome-shell$ cd extensions/
eduardo@MiPcLinux:~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions$ ls -l
total 64
drwxrwxr-x 4 eduardo eduardo 4096 sep  5 19:00 apps-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxrwxr-x 4 eduardo eduardo 4096 sep  5 19:00 auto-move-windows@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxrwxr-x 6 eduardo eduardo 4096 sep  5 20:12 bigSur-StatusArea@ordissimo.com
drwxrwxr-x 3 eduardo eduardo 4096 sep  5 18:59 drive-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxrwxr-x 4 eduardo eduardo 4096 sep  2 20:05 hibernate-status@dromi
drwxrwxr-x 4 eduardo eduardo 4096 sep  5 19:16 hplip-menu2@grizzlysmit.smit.id.au
drwxrwxr-x 2 eduardo eduardo 4096 sep  5 19:02 launch-new-instance@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxrwxr-x 3 eduardo eduardo 4096 sep  5 19:03 native-window-placement@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxrwxr-x 6 eduardo eduardo 4096 sep  5 19:09 openweather-extension@jenslody.de
drwxrwxr-x 3 eduardo eduardo 4096 sep  5 18:55 places-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxrwxr-x 7 eduardo eduardo 4096 sep  5 19:11 sound-output-device-chooser@kgshank.net
drwxrwxr-x 4 eduardo eduardo 4096 sep  5 17:30 system-monitor-next@paradoxxx.zero.gmail.com
drwxrwxr-x 3 eduardo eduardo 4096 sep  5 17:23 user-theme@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxrwxr-x 4 eduardo eduardo 4096 sep  5 19:06 window-list@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxrwxr-x 2 eduardo eduardo 4096 sep  5 19:07 windowsNavigator@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxrwxr-x 3 eduardo eduardo 4096 sep  5 18:58 workspace-indicator@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
eduardo@MiPcLinux:~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions$ cd ..
eduardo@MiPcLinux:~/.local/share/gnome-shell$ cd extension-updates/
eduardo@MiPcLinux:~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extension-updates$ ls -l
total 0
```

I said in other posts, ive upgraded from 20.04 to 22.04.1 and im in process of customizing and clenaning, and trying to fix problems. This did not happen in my gnome top bar in 20.04...i ve a problem in my view and its very disturbing working with that blinking....

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what your issue is by watching the video. Can you describe a bit what we see? Is it that the items in your top panel are a bit dimmer? Have you tried to disable all extensions, reboot, and see if your problem gets fixed? Please [edit] your question to add this additional information.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem because in Gnome Tweaks -> Appearance -> Start up applications -> I had two or three that i suppose that came from upgrading. I delete them and the problem was gone.

Id like to add them back and delete one by one, to know exactly which one or which ones cause the problem.I attach a image in spanish, but quite self explanatory ( you always have google Translator=

Thanks

[image]